# Bad Substitution when Renaming Files using find

Tags: bash, replace, find

I am trying to recursively rename image files using the [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command.

Currently, the command is written as follows:

```
$ find . -name '*.jpg' -exec rename "${echo $(uuidgen) | cut -c1-8}.jpg" '{}' \;
```

And it errors with:

> bash: `${echo $(uuidgen) | cut -c1-8}.jpg`: bad substitution

I've tried various combinations of using `{}` and `()` but nothing seems to work. If I run `echo $(uuidgen) | cut -c1-8` on its own, the correct result is produced, so I just want to simply interpolate this String into the image name.

If I conduct the substitution as follows:

```
$ find . -name '*.jpg' -exec rename "$(echo $(uuidgen) | cut -c1-8).jpg" '{}' \;
```

The command errors with:

> Bareword "jpg" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at (eval 1) line 1.

How can I fix these issues?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your bash error is caused by using `${ .. }` around `echo ...|cut` not `$( .. )`. But fixing that exposes a rename error as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `man rename`:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> rename [ -v ] [ -n ] [ -f ] perlexpr [ files ]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> "rename" renames the filenames supplied according to the rule specified as the first argument.  The
>          perlexpr argument is a Perl expression which is expected to modify the $_ string in Perl for at least some
>          of the filenames specified.  If a given filename is not modified by the expression, it will not be renamed.
>          If no filenames are given on the command line, filenames will be read via standard input.

The first argument is thus a regular expression. You need to change the first argument to a regex that match any string and replace it with: `$(echo $(uuidgen) | cut -c1-8).jpg`

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec rename 's/.*/$(echo $(uuidgen) | cut -c1-8).jpg/' '{}' \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `mv` instead `rename`.

```
find . -name '*.jpg' -exec mv '{}' "$(echo $(uuidgen) | cut -c1-8).jpg"  \;
```